# Display excel on web applications

Tags: excel, web-applications, local-storage

Please describe the ways by which I can display excel sheets in my hard disk drive on my web application. Excel files will be on my local storage. Please provide the possible methods and also the easiest and fastest way.

Comment: .mht format will open the excel file in a web browser... but not sure if you will be able to use it in an web server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display the excel  file as  it is  in the web  application or  want to use  any particular format in  doing  so ??

In both the cases use  any file reading and  writing JAVA API and you will be  able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Its displayed by reading the excel and creating a table, tr and td elem. But the problem is its not functioning properly when too many rows are present. So we need a better way of handling load. So is there a ready to use API, like there is for embedding docs from onedrive or skydrive